# hyperref pdf table of contents messed up (probably bookmarks problem)

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I have trouble with my thesis document. The sidebar table of contents (when opening in a pdf viewer) has a wrong ordering. Even though chapter 1 and chapter 2 are on the same hierarchical plane in the sidebar pdf toc chapter 2 is under chapter 1 (and chapter 3 and all other chapters are under chapter 2).

The normal table of contents in the document is fine. I think it has something with bookmarks (which I'm not 100% sure what they are).

After I fix a mistake in my latex document and latex doesn't compile fully. The next compile ends with the error:

`Runaway argument?`

{\376\377\0002\000.\0005\000.\0001\000\040\000R\000o\000t\000a\000t\0\ETC.
./thesis.tex:293 (which is \begin{document}: File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.

trashing the aux file clears that and the next compile is fine again (the ordering of the pdf toc is still messed up).

How do I debug that? I can't really disable packages as they are tightly integrated. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in a macro where its contents is also set as a bookmark. However, I suppose yor thesis will be printed. Why do you then need hyperref?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bookmarks are the things in the sidebar. The runaway error probably means that one of your `\chapter` etc command contains something which breaks when hyperref tries to put it in the bookmark. Inspect the aux and the out file. Perhaps you can find the culprit. Or put `\end{document}` in the middle of your document and then move it around until you find the point where the error appears.

Comment: Answer:

There were a couple of problems and one of them or the combination of them solved it.

Glossaries should not be referred to in captions even with \glsentryname.

For multiple appendices I used \begin{appendices} and \end{appendices}.

Both of these combined and the bookmarks work again.

Comment: You can try to protect fragile commands with `\protect\gls...`. Or use `\texorpdfstring`: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=texorpdf

Answer (score 3):

For those wanting another solution: I found trashing (clearing) the `.aux` files and re-running LaTeX helped me with the same error.

I think the issue is that my co-author made some edits, and when I pulled them and ran LaTeX, it did an incremental update with some bad info in the `.aux` files. Clearing them and re-running helped.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked.

Comment: But the issue keeps happening again and again. I don't know what's the root cause :(